# Existence of Green's functions for PDEs

Tags: reference-request, linear-pde, green-function

Here is what I think I know: Given a symmetric linear differential operator $\mathcal{L}$ that is positive definite on a function space(/space of distributions) $\mathcal{H}$, we can find its inverse, which we know will be an integral transform due to the Schwartz kernel theorem. The kernel of the transform will be the Green's function $\mathcal{G}$ corresponding to $\mathcal{L}$ on $\mathcal{H}$.

So what about the other way around? If I have a symmetric positive definite kernel $\mathcal{G}$ on $\mathcal{H}$, will there always exist a linear differential operator $\mathcal{L}$ for which $\mathcal{L}\mathcal{G}(\cdot, t)=\delta_{t}$?

Comment: I think the simple answer is No, simply because it's not so hard to find examples of integral kernels whose inverses are not differential operators. Also, see this [earlier question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/92948/2622).

Comment: For example, the Gaussian $G(x,y) = \exp(-|x-y|^2/\sigma^2)$ corresponds to a differential operator of infinite order.

Comment: Dear @PeterMichor. Thank you for your answer. Excuse my lack of knowledge, but why is the infinite series expansion of differential operators that have a Gaussian Green's function not a linear differential operator?

Comment: Differential operators are usually constrained to be of finite (or at least locally finite order). Otherwise, the line gets blurred, e.g., you could consider the translation $f(x) \mapsto f(x+y)$ as a differential operator of infinite order as well.